# Userform to answer original userform

Tags: excel, vba, encoding, userform

I have created a night shift handover using a Userform[image: Userform], it works well and populates the database attached[image: Database].

I am trying to add another userform that allows the person to reply saying what work was carried out, There is a unique column "Event Number" that goes up by 1 for every entry.

I can create the userform for this reply but not sure how i can get it to coincide with the one raised for them. I had thought the first text box could be used for what event are you replying to? if the event number typed in is 1 then it would populate cells in the same row as event 1, likewise as you move up through the event numbers.

Probably not explained this very well, very new to VBA and trying to learn as quickly as possible.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Second userform has been created and asking for an event number, unsure of what coding to use to allow this to populate the same row as the event number is in.